# Navicat utf8 not working on mysql database

Tags: mysql, utf-8, expressionengine, navicat

I'm currently trying to merge data changes between two out of sync expressionengine databases. For this i have opted to use navicat.

The website makes heavy use of the greek character set in templates. When I view greek table field data in phpmyadmin, I see the characters in greek as expected. When I load them up into Navicat, I only see "???" question marks in their place. When I try to sync data between the databases, the result is that question marks are put in the place of greek characters.

The field types in question are "text" using "utf8_general_ci".

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Under connection's properties, in Advanced tab set encoding to Auto. This is for navicat 15.0.22

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probem with Navicat Linux... The problem was solved following these steps:

1. In Navicat, open your table in design view.
2. Under Fields tab, select the fields which require to show as Unicode. Change the Character set and Collation into utf8 and uft8_general_ci.
3. Under Options tab, change the Character set and Collation into utf8--UTF-8 Unicode and uft8_general_ci.
4. Save.
5. Select Tools > Options. Under Font, change the "Editor Font" into e.g. AR PL ZenKai Uni .
6. Re-start your Navicat.

   - Select the correct "Editor Font" in Options until it shows your data correctly. (Repeat steps 5 and 6 above.)

Source: http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/How_can_I_display_Unicode_in_Linux%3F

Comment: i use `DejaVu Sans` fonts for arabic chars

Comment: Thank you for your input, I use navicat 12.1, I have followed your stepss 1,2,3,4,but could not find a font  AR PL ZenKai Uni on step 5.

I use windows 10 on a pc. My database is for a multilingual website and the chinese etc appears as ???????

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue and saw there is no proper answer.
The solution is:
In Connection Properties... for your MySql database, click on the Advanced tab and check (tick if you're from UK) the box for "Use MySql character set" and then your tables will display correctly.