# Can't save and display data correctly

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, navicat

When I'm trying to add data in database and fetch it in data-grid, all the Sindhi characters turn in "???????????" as shown in figure. i think its because of coding i.e Unicode, ASCII etc, i don't know what coding is compatible for Sindhi and how to use it. Kindly refer me material to understand and to solve this problem as I'm am newbie in C#.[image: this problems i have shown in below picture, you can see record at id 5 is saved with question marks in navicat, same appears in the application when i upgrade or add things in Sindhi, kindly guide me]

Comment: Set encoding to utf.

Comment: where should i set it to utd ?

Comment: In both, database and your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the characterset to utf8, for instructions on how to do that reffer to the answer to this question.

[Navicat utf8 not working on mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156727/navicat-utf8-not-working-on-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Set Your DataType as `Nvarchar(1000)` in `C#` as well as `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by

1. going in navicat
2. open table in design view
3. in tabs there is Options tab inside options tab I changed character set  and collation to UTF8

Comment: and also set utf encoding in coing where you provide path for sql